# Let $S$ be the set of all real numbers $r$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ for infinitely many real number $x$.Find the number of elements in set $S.$

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ and let $g(x)=\frac{rx}{1-x}$
Let $S$ be the set of all real numbers $r$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ for infinitely many real number $x$.Find the number of elements in set $S.$

---

I found out $f(g(x))=\frac{rx}{1-x+rx}$ and $g(f(x))=rx$
But i do not know how to solve it further.I am stuck here.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Just solve the equation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two cases:

1. $r=0$.
2. If $r\ne 0$, as $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ for infinitely many values of $x$, it is satisfied in particular for a non-zero value, hence we can simplify by $rx$, getting
   $$\frac1{1+(r-1)x}=1\iff 1+(r-1)x =1\iff (r-1)x=0\iff r=1.$$